# Object Home Page Rebuilt as Custom Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, custom, object

Out of curiosity, has anyone run across a custom Visualforce page which essentially mimics an object home page? While I understand that custom buttons can't be added to the standard home pages, but can be added to the List Views, it would be really cool to be able a custom button to the object home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly *could*, as the APIs needed are available (e.g. querying recently created, recently updated, recently viewed), plus whatever you wanted to do. It's not exactly a stroll in the park, but could be built to suit your specifications. The question you have to ask though is certainly "is this really worth it?" For a single button, you might want to just leave it on the list view. However, if you have substantially new customizations, you might find it worth your time.

Comment: First, just want to thank you for being such an awesome member of the community. I think you've had an answer on every question I've asked here! Haha. Second, I guess my next question is why this hasn't been created as an app yet? It'd be time-consuming to build the first page, but then easily duplicated for every standard object. It's also weird that the source code for the object home pages isn't provided by Salesforce in any fashion.